# redirecting URL using meta tag

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

After typing domain name which is `http://example.com` on my web browser, I see Apache generic page as shown below:

[image]

As I figured out, it's shown because there is no `index.html` file present inside `/var/www/html` folder. I placed an index file like the following and tried to redirect this generic page to the page of my website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=https://example.com/my_app/browser/exercise/myfile.html">

</head>


<body>

<h1>This is Apache's Index.html</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

This thing works fine but my network team says that this redirect will break the site when connecting from outside the network. I am wondering if this is a right way to do this or should I go with `mod_rewrite` module of Apache? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: I have always used HTTP 301 redirect.

Answer (score -1):

Simply set Apache's default page using .htaccess. It is very well described by PlantTheldea here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322414/448979

Comment: please do not go recommending modify things in .htaccess as first option, it adds overhead and makes things way more complicated, most times per-dir configurations are not necessary.

Comment: Which option should I follow?

Comment: Administrator's choice. :-)

Comment: @CorneliusJ.vanDyk I didn't understand what do you meant by `Administrator's choice`. I am the one configuring the apache.